# Apache log4j is not installed with the latest version from Spring Initialzr?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, log4j, slf4j

I created a new Spring app using Initialzr. After setting it up, I found out that the initial installation of the packages of log4j is not coming with the latest version (2.14.1 instead of 2.16.0 to combat the recent vulnerability attack). Checking the generated build.gradle also does not show the log4j package being mentioned.

Two questions regarding this:

1. Why dit Spring Initialzr not picking up the latest version of log4j?
2. To update this, do I need to specifically add the dependency in build.gradle itself?

Comment: Hello @OreoFanatics, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New version will be released on Dec 23 according to Spring blog

https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot